# .Net Core Dependency Injection without passing Dependency in Constructor

Tags: .net-core, c#-4.0, dependency-injection, authorize-attribute

I am implementing custom  [Authorize] attribute. Inside the OnAuthorization method in IdentityAuthorizeFilter Class, I need to have access to DBContext to perform Database checks. I can not pass the context in the constructor of the Class. How can I access DBContext inside this class ?

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{            
            services.AddDbContext<SecureContext>(options =>
                  options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SecureContext")));
}
```

CustomAuthorize:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class IdentityAuthorizeAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
{
    public IdentityAuthorizeAttribute(string permissions)
        : base(typeof(IdentityAuthorizeFilter))
    {
        Arguments = new object[] { permissions };
    }
}

public class IdentityAuthorizeFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{

    public IdentityAuthorizeFilter(string permissions) => Permissions = permissions;
    public string Permissions { get; set; }


    [Authorize]
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var claims = context.HttpContext.User.Claims.ToList();
        var auth = context.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;

        //Access DB Context
        
        if (!isAuthorized)
            context.Result = new UnauthorizedResult();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work?

```
var dbContext = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<SecureContext>();
```

I'm not sure if it will, but I did something similar using Microsoft's AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp method like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(
        options =>
        {
            configuration.Bind("AzureAD", options);
            options.Events ??= new OpenIdConnectEvents();
            options.Events.OnTokenValidated += async tokenValidatedContext =>
            {
                var dbContext = tokenValidatedContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<dbContext>();
                // Do stuff with db context here
            };
        });
```